# Why is truncated-at-n-chars mean n - 3 in Python?

Tags: python, truncate

EDIT: I didn't even think about the "..." being part of n. Sorry, guys! (and thank you)

I'm not sure if the "question" is missing something, or if I'm missing something. I am supposed to write a function in python that returns truncated-at-n-chars version of phrase. The docstring is as follows:

```
"""Return truncated-at-n-chars version of phrase.

If the phrase is longer than n, make sure it ends with '...' and is no
longer than n.

    >>> truncate("Hello World", 6)
    'Hel...'

    >>> truncate("Problem solving is the best!", 10)
    'Problem...'

    >>> truncate("Yo", 100)
    'Yo'

The smallest legal value of n is 3; if less, return a message:

    >>> truncate('Cool', 1)
    'Truncation must be at least 3 characters.'

    >>> truncate("Woah", 4)
    'W...'

    >>> truncate("Woah", 3)
    '...'
"""
```

Solution is:

```
if n < 3:
    return "Truncation must be at least 3 characters."

if n > len(phrase) + 2:
    return phrase

return phrase[:n - 3] + "..."
```

So why is it n-3? Is it because it says "The smallest legal value of n is 3"? Because when I google it, less than 3 is possible. Even if it wasn't, why isn't it just return phrase[:n] + "..."?

Comment: It seems it's because n-chars *includes* the three dots `...`. For `truncate("Hello World", 6)`, `n=6` means 3 chars from Hello World + the 3 dots. This is not a Python-specific question, that's just the requirement of the problem.

Comment: Try to walk through your code with example inputs you've provided.

Comment: I will say that "truncating" an n length string to n characters by replacing the last three chars with dots leaves room for improvement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why the solution includes n-3 is because you have to make sure that you leave 3 characters from the end so that you can add on the "...". For example, if you had the word "Elephant" and you had to truncate it at 5 characters. The input would look something like this

```
truncate("Elephant", 5)
```

and the output would look like this

```
'El...'
```

As you can see, I am not using the first 5 characters of the word 'Elephant,' but rather only the first 2, because each dot (.) counts as a character as well, so I must subtract 3 from n to count each dot (.) as well. Hope this answers your question!